# Jquery - Live position of block!

Tags: jquery, css, live

I have an element that moves on hover up or down. I need to know the position on that block and see in an text

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var who = $(".back");
var pozitie = who.position();
$("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + pozitie.top);
</script>
```

This script gives me only the start position. I need the position all the time. Can someone help?

Comment: How are you moving it? and do you want it updated with every step of the animation (if there is one) or just at the beginning/end?

Comment: I`s animated by an LavaLamp script, if you know this plugin. I`m new to jquery.... Thank you for answering!

Comment: on mouse move ,you need current position right?

Comment: I`v got the answer. I think I can handle from here to get my slider smooth. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var actualPosition = function() {
   var who = $(".back"),
      pozitie = who.position();
   $("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + pozitie.top);
};

// this
setInterval(actualPosition, 1000);
// or this
who_moves_event_function() {
    //...
    actualPosition();
    //...
}
</script>
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! YOU ARE AN GENIUS! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I appreciate your help. I can`t vote because I`m new here!

Comment: @Adyz - Be sure to accept an answer if it resolves your problem via the empty checkmark beside it  :)

Answer (score 0):

**This will give you current position all the time mouse move**

```
$(".back").hover(function(e) {
    // mouse over
    $("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + e.pageY+ "LEFT:" + e.pageX);
}, function() {
    // mouse out
    $("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + e.pageY+ "LEFT:" + e.pageX);
});


$(".back").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + e.pageY+ "LEFT:" + e.pageX);
});
```

Comment: Cool function! Maybe I will need-it one day. Thank you very much!

Comment: isnt this what you are looking, if not explain with detail, may be i can be exact.

Comment: I found the answer 
var actualPosition = function() {
   var who = $(".back"),
      pozitie = who.position();
   $("p.pozitie").text("TOP:" + pozitie.top);
};

// this
setInterval(actualPosition, 1000);

Comment: great , so you wanted position based on time